Find and Replace RegEx with WildCard PowerShell
I am trying to do a Find/Replace on multiple XMLs using PowerShell. I have most of the find/replaces working (where its straight-forward find/replace but one of the requirements is to find any occurrence of XML attribute FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD="XXXX" where XXXX stands for multiple different values and replace it with FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD="SYSTEM"
This is part of my PS Script which does the Find/Replace. The last Replace is doing nothing. I have tried many combinations but none seem to work. Any feedback on how this can be done would be great.
foreach ($sourcexml in Get-ChildItem $SRC_DIR\*.xml) 
{
"Translating $($sourcexml) ..." | Tee-Object -file $LOG_FILE -Append

 (Get-Content "$($sourcexml)") | ForEach-Object {
    $_.replace('DATACENTER="XXXX"', 'DATACENTER="YYYY"').replace('FOLDER_DSN="XXXX', 'FOLDER_DSN="YYYY').replace("**FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD=*\d+*", "FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD=SYSTEM"**)
 } | Set-Content "$($TRN_DIR)\$($sourcexml.Name)"
}

Sample XML: Type 1
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<!-- XML Utils Details: version 9.0.0. Exported at 20240524-230059 by SUBRAV15 from server SEMAU01 -->
<DEFTABLE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Folder.xsd">
    <FOLDER DATACENTER="XXXL" ENFORCE_VALIDATION="Y" FOLDER_DSN="XXX.XXX.SCHEDULE" FOLDER_NAME="XXXP0020" FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD="SYSTEM" PLATFORM="MVS" REAL_FOLDER_ID="0" SITE_STANDARD_NAME="Bypass_SiteStandard" TYPE="1" USED_BY_CODE="0" VERSION="919">
        <ADDITIONAL_FOLDER_DETAILS >
            <BUSINESS_PARAMETER NAME="APP_CODE" VALUE="XXX"/>
        </ADDITIONAL_FOLDER_DETAILS>
        <JOB
            APPLICATION="XXX"
            APPL_TYPE="OS"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="1"
            CHANGE_DATE="20240518"
            CHANGE_TIME="053813"
            CHANGE_USERID="XXX"
            CONFCAL="XXX_ALL"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="XXX13"
            CREATION_DATE="20240305"
            CREATION_TIME="215525"
            CREATION_USER="XXX"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DOCMEM="XXXF0105"
            DUE_OUT="1230"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="S"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="1"
            JOB_VERSION="01.00"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="1"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="1"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="XXX.XXX.JCL"
            MEMNAME="XXXF0105"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            OVERRIDE_PATH="XXX.XXX.OVERLIB.JCL.XXXF"
            PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0020"
            PREVENTNCT2="Y"
            PRIORITY="A0"
            RETEN_DAYS="005"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="UIDDFLT"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SHIFTNUM="+00"
            SUB_APPLICATION="XXXF000-XXXTO"
            SYSDB="1"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMEFROM="1200"
            TIMETO="&gt;"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
            WEEKDAYS="D0W1">
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXF0105_XXXF0105_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXXF" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXX" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%$LASTRUNDT" VALUE="23246/1200"/>
            <SHOUT DEST="U-ECS" MESSAGE="S %%JOBNAME #%%ORDERID ENDED NOTOK! PSSCTICKET" URGENCY="R" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
            <ON CODE="C****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOACTION ACTION="OK"/>
            </ON>
            <ON CODE="*****,****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Change Class" PAR="*"/>
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Release"/>
            </ON>
        </JOB>
    </FOLDER>
</DEFTABLE>

Sample XML: Type 2
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<DEFTABLE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Folder.xsd">
    <SMART_FOLDER
        ADJUST_COND="N"
        APPLICATION="XXX"
        APPL_TYPE="OS"
        APR="0"
        AUG="0"
        AUTOARCH="1"
        CONFIRM="0"
        CREATED_BY="XXX13"
        CREATION_DATE="20240305"
        CREATION_TIME="215525"
        CREATION_USER="XXX"
        CRITICAL="0"
        CYCLIC="0"
        CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
        CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
        DATACENTER="XXXL"
        DAYSKEEPINNOTOK="0"
        DAYS_AND_OR="O"
        DEC="0"
        DOCMEM="XXXC5I00"
        ENFORCE_VALIDATION="Y"
        FEB="0"
        FOLDER_DSN="XXX.XXX.SCHEDULE"
        FOLDER_NAME="XXXP0501"
        FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD = 1
        IND_CYCLIC="S"
        INTERVAL="00001M"
        JAN="0"
        JOBISN="1"
        JUL="0"
        JUN="0"
        MAR="0"
        MAXDAYS="0"
        MAXRERUN="0"
        MAXRUNS="0"
        MAXWAIT="1"
        MAY="0"
        MEMNAME="XXXP0501"
        NOV="0"
        OCT="0"
        PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0501"
        PLATFORM="MVS"
        REAL_FOLDER_ID="0"
        REMOVEATONCE="Y"
        RETRO="0"
        RUN_AS="PXXX01"
        SEP="0"
        SHIFT="Ignore Job"
        SITE_STANDARD_NAME="Bypass_SiteStandard"
        SUB_APPLICATION="XXXCS"
        SYSDB="1"
        TASKTYPE="SMART Table"
        TYPE="2"
        USED_BY_CODE="0"
        USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
        VERSION="919"
>
        <RULE_BASED_CALENDAR
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            FEB="1"
            JAN="1"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            LEVEL="N"
            MAR="1"
            MAXWAIT="00"
            MAY="1"
            NAME="001_XXXC5I00"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            RETRO="0"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"/>
        <ADDITIONAL_FOLDER_DETAILS >
            <BUSINESS_PARAMETER NAME="APP_CODE" VALUE="XXX"/>
        </ADDITIONAL_FOLDER_DETAILS>
        <JOB
            APPLICATION="XXX"
            APPL_TYPE="OS"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="1"
            CHANGE_DATE="20240518"
            CHANGE_TIME="053856"
            CHANGE_USERID="XXX"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="XXX13"
            CREATION_DATE="20240305"
            CREATION_TIME="215525"
            CREATION_USER="XXX"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="XXX"
            DOCMEM="XXXC5R00"
            END_FOLDER="N"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="S"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="4"
            JOB_VERSION="01.00"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="1"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="1"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="XXX.XXX.JCL"
            MEMNAME="XXXC5R00"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            OVERRIDE_PATH="XXX.XXX.OVERLIB.JCL.XXXF"
            PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0501"
            PREVENTNCT2="Y"
            PRIORITY="A0"
            RETEN_DAYS="005"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="PXXX01"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SUB_APPLICATION="XXXF000-XXXCS"
            SYSDB="1"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMETO="&gt;"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
>
            <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5I99-XXXC5R00!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
            <RULE_BASED_CALENDARS NAME="*"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R00-XXXC5R30!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5I99-XXXC5R00!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="-"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXXF" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXX" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%$LASTRUNDT" VALUE="10170/1057"/>
            <SHOUT DEST="U-ECS" MESSAGE="I %%JOBNAME #%%ORDERID ENDED NOTOK!" URGENCY="R" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
            <ON CODE="&lt;C0008" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOACTION ACTION="OK"/>
            </ON>
            <ON CODE="*****,****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Change Class" PAR="*"/>
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Release"/>
            </ON>
        </JOB>
        <JOB
            APPLICATION="XXX"
            APPL_TYPE="OS"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="1"
            CHANGE_DATE="20240518"
            CHANGE_TIME="053856"
            CHANGE_USERID="XXX"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="XXX13"
            CREATION_DATE="20240305"
            CREATION_TIME="215525"
            CREATION_USER="XXX"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="XXX"
            DOCMEM="XXXC5R30"
            END_FOLDER="N"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="S"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="5"
            JOB_VERSION="01.00"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="1"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="1"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="XXX.XXX.JCL"
            MEMNAME="XXXC5R30"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            OVERRIDE_PATH="XXX.XXX.OVERLIB.JCL.XXXF"
            PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0501"
            PREVENTNCT2="Y"
            PRIORITY="A0"
            RETEN_DAYS="005"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="PXXX01"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SUB_APPLICATION="XXXF000-XXXCS"
            SYSDB="1"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMETO="&gt;"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
>
            <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R00-XXXC5R30!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
            <RULE_BASED_CALENDARS NAME="*"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R30-XXXC5R35!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R00-XXXC5R30!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="-"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXXF" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXX" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%$LASTRUNDT" VALUE="10170/1057"/>
            <SHOUT DEST="U-ECS" MESSAGE="I %%JOBNAME #%%ORDERID ENDED NOTOK!" URGENCY="R" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
            <ON CODE="&lt;C0008" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOACTION ACTION="OK"/>
            </ON>
            <ON CODE="*****,****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Change Class" PAR="*"/>
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Release"/>
            </ON>
        </JOB>
        <JOB
            APPLICATION="XXX"
            APPL_TYPE="OS"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="1"
            CHANGE_DATE="20240518"
            CHANGE_TIME="053856"
            CHANGE_USERID="XXX"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="XXX13"
            CREATION_DATE="20240305"
            CREATION_TIME="215525"
            CREATION_USER="XXX"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="XXX"
            DOCMEM="XXXC5R35"
            END_FOLDER="N"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="S"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="6"
            JOB_VERSION="01.00"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="1"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="1"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="XXX.XXX.JCL"
            MEMNAME="XXXC5R35"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            OVERRIDE_PATH="XXX.XXX.OVERLIB.JCL.XXXF"
            PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0501"
            PREVENTNCT2="Y"
            PRIORITY="A0"
            RETEN_DAYS="005"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="PXXX01"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SUB_APPLICATION="XXXF000-XXXCS"
            SYSDB="1"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMETO="&gt;"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
>
            <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R30-XXXC5R35!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
            <RULE_BASED_CALENDARS NAME="*"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R35-XXXC5R44!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R30-XXXC5R35!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="-"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXXF" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXX" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%$LASTRUNDT" VALUE="10170/1057"/>
            <SHOUT DEST="U-ECS" MESSAGE="I %%JOBNAME #%%ORDERID ENDED NOTOK!" URGENCY="R" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
            <ON CODE="&lt;C0008" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOACTION ACTION="OK"/>
            </ON>
            <ON CODE="*****,****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Change Class" PAR="*"/>
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Release"/>
            </ON>
        </JOB>
        <JOB
            APPLICATION="XXX"
            APPL_TYPE="OS"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="1"
            CHANGE_DATE="20240518"
            CHANGE_TIME="053856"
            CHANGE_USERID="XXX"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="XXX13"
            CREATION_DATE="20240305"
            CREATION_TIME="215525"
            CREATION_USER="XXX"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="XXX"
            DOCMEM="XXXC5R44"
            END_FOLDER="N"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="S"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="7"
            JOB_VERSION="01.00"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="1"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="1"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="XXX.XXX.JCL"
            MEMNAME="XXXC5R44"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            OVERRIDE_PATH="XXX.XXX.OVERLIB.JCL.XXXF"
            PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0501"
            PREVENTNCT2="Y"
            PRIORITY="A0"
            RETEN_DAYS="005"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="PXXX01"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SUB_APPLICATION="XXXF000-XXXCS"
            SYSDB="1"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMETO="&gt;"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
>
            <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R35-XXXC5R44!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
            <RULE_BASED_CALENDARS NAME="*"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R44-XXXC5R48!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R35-XXXC5R44!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="-"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXXF" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXX" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%$LASTRUNDT" VALUE="10170/1057"/>
            <SHOUT DEST="U-ECS" MESSAGE="I %%JOBNAME #%%ORDERID ENDED NOTOK!" URGENCY="R" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
            <ON CODE="&lt;C0008" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOACTION ACTION="OK"/>
            </ON>
            <ON CODE="*****,****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Change Class" PAR="*"/>
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Release"/>
            </ON>
        </JOB>
        <JOB
            APPLICATION="XXX"
            APPL_TYPE="OS"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="1"
            CHANGE_DATE="20240518"
            CHANGE_TIME="053856"
            CHANGE_USERID="XXX"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="XXX13"
            CREATION_DATE="20240305"
            CREATION_TIME="215525"
            CREATION_USER="XXX"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="XXX"
            DOCMEM="XXXC5R48"
            END_FOLDER="N"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="S"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="8"
            JOB_VERSION="01.00"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="1"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="1"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="XXX.XXX.JCL"
            MEMNAME="XXXC5R48"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            OVERRIDE_PATH="XXX.XXX.OVERLIB.JCL.XXXF"
            PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0501"
            PREVENTNCT2="Y"
            PRIORITY="A0"
            RETEN_DAYS="005"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="PXXX01"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SUB_APPLICATION="XXXF000-XXXCS"
            SYSDB="1"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMETO="&gt;"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
>
            <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R44-XXXC5R48!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
            <RULE_BASED_CALENDARS NAME="*"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R48-XXXC5R49!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R44-XXXC5R48!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="-"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXXF" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXX" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%$LASTRUNDT" VALUE="10170/1057"/>
            <SHOUT DEST="U-ECS" MESSAGE="I %%JOBNAME #%%ORDERID ENDED NOTOK!" URGENCY="R" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
            <ON CODE="&lt;C0008" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOACTION ACTION="OK"/>
            </ON>
            <ON CODE="*****,****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Change Class" PAR="*"/>
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Release"/>
            </ON>
        </JOB>
        <JOB
            APPLICATION="XXX"
            APPL_TYPE="OS"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="1"
            CHANGE_DATE="20240518"
            CHANGE_TIME="053856"
            CHANGE_USERID="XXX"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="XXX13"
            CREATION_DATE="20240305"
            CREATION_TIME="215525"
            CREATION_USER="XXX"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="XXX"
            DOCMEM="XXXC5R49"
            END_FOLDER="N"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="S"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="9"
            JOB_VERSION="01.00"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="1"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="1"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="XXX.XXX.JCL"
            MEMNAME="XXXC5R49"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            OVERRIDE_PATH="XXX.XXX.OVERLIB.JCL.XXXF"
            PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0501"
            PREVENTNCT2="Y"
            PRIORITY="A0"
            RETEN_DAYS="005"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="PXXX01"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SUB_APPLICATION="XXXF000-XXXCS"
            SYSDB="1"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMETO="&gt;"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
>
            <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R48-XXXC5R49!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
            <RULE_BASED_CALENDARS NAME="*"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R49-XXXC5R99!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R48-XXXC5R49!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="-"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXXF" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXX" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%$LASTRUNDT" VALUE="10170/1058"/>
            <SHOUT DEST="U-ECS" MESSAGE="I %%JOBNAME #%%ORDERID ENDED NOTOK!" URGENCY="R" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
            <ON CODE="&lt;C0008" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOACTION ACTION="OK"/>
            </ON>
            <ON CODE="*****,****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Change Class" PAR="*"/>
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Release"/>
            </ON>
        </JOB>
        <JOB
            APPLICATION="XXX"
            APPL_TYPE="OS"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="1"
            CHANGE_DATE="20240518"
            CHANGE_TIME="053856"
            CHANGE_USERID="XXX"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="XXX13"
            CREATION_DATE="20240305"
            CREATION_TIME="215525"
            CREATION_USER="XXX"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="XXX"
            DOCMEM="XXXC5R99"
            END_FOLDER="N"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="S"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="10"
            JOB_VERSION="01.00"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="1"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="1"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="XXX.XXX.JCL"
            MEMNAME="XXXC5R99"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            OVERRIDE_PATH="XXX.XXX.OVERLIB.JCL.XXXF"
            PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0501"
            PREVENTNCT2="Y"
            PRIORITY="A0"
            RETEN_DAYS="005"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="PXXX01"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SUB_APPLICATION="XXXF000-XXXCS"
            SYSDB="1"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMETO="&gt;"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
>
            <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R49-XXXC5R99!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
            <RULE_BASED_CALENDARS NAME="*"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R99-XXXC5S00!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R49-XXXC5R99!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="-"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXXF" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXX" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%$LASTRUNDT" VALUE="10170/1058"/>
            <SHOUT DEST="U-ECS" MESSAGE="I %%JOBNAME #%%ORDERID ENDED NOTOK!" URGENCY="R" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
            <ON CODE="&lt;C0008" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOACTION ACTION="OK"/>
            </ON>
            <ON CODE="*****,****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Change Class" PAR="*"/>
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Release"/>
            </ON>
        </JOB>
        <JOB
            APPLICATION="XXX"
            APPL_TYPE="OS"
            APR="1"
            AUG="1"
            AUTOARCH="1"
            CHANGE_DATE="20240518"
            CHANGE_TIME="053856"
            CHANGE_USERID="XXX"
            CONFIRM="0"
            CREATED_BY="XXX13"
            CREATION_DATE="20240305"
            CREATION_TIME="215525"
            CREATION_USER="XXX"
            CRITICAL="0"
            CYCLIC="0"
            CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0"
            CYCLIC_TYPE="C"
            DAYS_AND_OR="O"
            DEC="1"
            DESCRIPTION="XXX"
            DOCMEM="XXXC5S00"
            END_FOLDER="N"
            FEB="1"
            IND_CYCLIC="S"
            INTERVAL="00001M"
            JAN="1"
            JOBISN="11"
            JOB_VERSION="01.00"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="1"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="1"
            MAY="1"
            MEMLIB="XXX.XXX.JCL"
            MEMNAME="XXXC5S00"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            OVERRIDE_PATH="XXX.XXX.OVERLIB.JCL.XXXF"
            PARENT_FOLDER="XXXP0501"
            PREVENTNCT2="Y"
            PRIORITY="A0"
            RETEN_DAYS="005"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="PXXX01"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SUB_APPLICATION="XXXF000-XXXCS"
            SYSDB="1"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
            TIMETO="&gt;"
            USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
>
            <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R99-XXXC5S00!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
            <RULE_BASED_CALENDARS NAME="*"/>
            <OUTCOND NAME="XXXC5I00_XXXC5R99-XXXC5S00!000_OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="-"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXXF" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QRXXX" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%$LASTRUNDT" VALUE="10170/1058"/>
            <SHOUT DEST="U-ECS" MESSAGE="I %%JOBNAME #%%ORDERID ENDED NOTOK!" URGENCY="R" WHEN="NOTOK"/>
            <ON CODE="&lt;C0008" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOACTION ACTION="OK"/>
            </ON>
            <ON CODE="*****,****" PGMS="ANYSTEP">
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Change Class" PAR="*"/>
                <DOOUTPUT FROM="H" OPTION="Release"/>
            </ON>
        </JOB>
    </SMART_FOLDER>
</DEFTABLE>


Powershell is very capable of handling XML, so better not use textual replace methods on it. Having said that, please [edit] your question and add a valid (piece of) xml in there we can work with. Paste that in as formatted text

This and this  SO answer explain your problem.

[xml]$xml = get-content $sourcexml

@Theo - I have added piece of XML above and highlighted the attribute I am trying to update

Is this valid XML? Line 19: CYCLIC_TOLERANCEXXX0".

@lit - its a piece of a valid XML. I had replaced sensitive data with "XXX". Missed out on updating the one you have highlighted. Corrected it now

It is still not valid XML. DAYS_AND_ORXXXO"

Thanks for the new xml samples.
Here's my new code to deal with both Type1 and Type2 XML files.
# create a Hashtable with the new values. 
# the keys are the exact attribute names from the XML
$replacements = @{
    DATACENTER          = 'YYY'
    FOLDER_DSN          = 'YYYY'
    FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD = 'SYSTEM'
    # you can add more replacements in here
}

# prepare an xml object
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()

# gather and loop over the xml files (we just need the FullNames)
$xmlFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $SRC_DIR -Filter '*.xml' -File).FullName
foreach ($sourcexml in $xmlFiles) {
    try {
        # Load the xml file (this way will use the correct encoding of the file)
        $xml.Load($sourcexml)
    }
    catch {
        $logmsg = "Could not load $sourcexml`r`n   $($_.Exception.Message)"
        Write-Warning $logmsg
        Add-Content -Path $LOG_FILE -Value $logmsg
        continue  # skip this file and proceed with the next one
    }

    # determine if we have Type1 or Type2 XML
    $node = $xml.DEFTABLE.SelectSingleNode("./SMART_FOLDER")
    if (!$node) { $node = $xml.DEFTABLE.SelectSingleNode("./FOLDER") }
    if (!$node) { 
        $logmsg = "Could not find 'FOLDER' or 'SMART_FOLDER' node in $sourcexml"
        Write-Warning $logmsg
        Add-Content -Path $LOG_FILE -Value $logmsg
        continue  # skip this file and proceed with the next one
    }

    # start updating the xml
    "Translating $sourcexml ..." | Add-Content -Path $LOG_FILE -PassThru
    $updated = $false  # set a flag to check if we update anything

    # next loop over the items in the replacement Hash and set the new values
    $replacements.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        # only try to replace if the attribute exists
        if ($node.$($_.Key)) {
            $node.$($_.Key) = $_.Value
            $updated = $true
        }
        else {
            $logmsg = "Attribute $($_.Key) does not exist in $sourcexml"
            Write-Warning $logmsg
            Add-Content -Path $LOG_FILE -Value $logmsg
        }
    }

    # finally, save the updated xml to disk (if we updated anything..)
    if ($updated) { $xml.Save($sourcexml) }
}


To be able to not just overwrite the current attribute value as a whole, but also to replace its current value partially, you can change the code to:
# create an array of PsCustom Objects with the new values. 
# KeyName   the exact attribute name from the XML
# OldValue  (only used when Action = 'Replace') the part of the current value to replace
# NewValue  the value to replace with or to set as a whole for the xml attribut
# Action    can be either 'Set' to overwrite the current value fully or 'Replace'
$replacements = [PsCustomObject]@{ KeyName = 'DATACENTER'; OldValue = $null; NewValue = 'YYY'; Action = 'Set' },
                [PsCustomObject]@{ KeyName = 'FOLDER_DSN'; OldValue = 'AAA'; NewValue = 'BBB'; Action = 'Replace' },
                [PsCustomObject]@{ KeyName = 'FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD'; OldValue = $null; NewValue = 'SYSTEM'; Action = 'Set' }
                # you can add more here with either action 'Set' or 'Replace'

# prepare an xml object
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()

# gather and loop over the xml files (we just need the FullNames)
$xmlFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $SRC_DIR -Filter '*.xml' -File).FullName
foreach ($sourcexml in $xmlFiles) {
    try {
        # Load the xml file (this way will use the correct encoding of the file)
        $xml.Load($sourcexml)
    }
    catch {
        $logmsg = "Could not load $sourcexml`r`n   $($_.Exception.Message)"
        Write-Warning $logmsg
        Add-Content -Path $LOG_FILE -Value $logmsg
        continue  # skip this file and proceed with the next one
    }

    # determine if we have Type1 or Type2 XML
    $node = $xml.DEFTABLE.SelectSingleNode("./SMART_FOLDER")
    if (!$node) { $node = $xml.DEFTABLE.SelectSingleNode("./FOLDER") }
    if (!$node) { 
        $logmsg = "Could not find 'FOLDER' or 'SMART_FOLDER' node in $sourcexml"
        Write-Warning $logmsg
        Add-Content -Path $LOG_FILE -Value $logmsg
        continue  # skip this file and proceed with the next one
    }

    # start updating the xml
    "Translating $sourcexml ..." | Add-Content -Path $LOG_FILE -PassThru
    $updated = $false  # set a flag to check if we update anything

    # next loop over the items in the replacement array and set the new values
    foreach ($item in $replacements) {
        # only try to replace if the attribute exists
        if ($node.$($item.KeyName)) {
            switch ($item.Action) {
                'Replace' { $node.$($item.KeyName) = ($node.$($item.KeyName) -replace $item.OldValue, $item.NewValue) }
                default   { $node.$($item.KeyName) = $item.NewValue }  # if not Replace, then overwrite the current value
            }
            $updated = $true
        }
        else {
            $logmsg = "Attribute $($_.KeyName) does not exist in $sourcexml"
            Write-Warning $logmsg
            Add-Content -Path $LOG_FILE -Value $logmsg
        }
    }

    # finally, save the updated xml to disk (if we updated anything..)
    if ($updated) { $xml.Save($sourcexml) }
}

P.S. -replace is Case-Insensitive. If you need Case-Sensitive replacements, you can change to use the -creplace operator or the string .Replace() method

Firstly. Thanks a lot for helping me with this. If your code suggestion is going to use XML attributes that won't work for all my use cases. Because some of my XMLs will not have SMART_FOLDER Node and have FOLDER instead. So I have posted Full Sample Examples for both use case. Can you please amend your recommendation accordingly because as it is now, it is giving "the document does not have a root element" and "verify the property can be set" errors

This works like a charm. Thanks a lot for this and the explanation.
Just for my learning purposes, let's say I don't want to do a full replacement of a certain XML attribute instead do only a partial replacement, how do you recommend it could be integrated with your existing replacements instead of introducing another loop through.
Ex : FOLDER_DSN="AAA.XXX.XXX" to FOLDER_DSN="BBB.XXX.XXX"

were you able to look into my additional question

@venky_au Please see the new code I have added for that

Your current script needs refactoring to correctly capture and handle XML as well as regular expression.
Refer the code below:
foreach ($sourcexml in Get-ChildItem $SRC_DIR*.xml) {
    "Translating $($sourcexml) ..." | Tee-Object -file $LOG_FILE -Append

    (Get-Content "$($sourcexml)") | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace 'DATACENTER="[^"]*"', 'DATACENTER="YYYY"' `
           -replace 'FOLDER_DSN="[^"]*"', 'FOLDER_DSN="YYYY"' `
           -replace 'FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD="[^"]*"', 'FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD="SYSTEM"'
    } | Set-Content "$($TRN_DIR)$($sourcexml.Name)"
}


Thanks but this is not working either. It does not do any of the find/replaces.

Depending on the original XML, working with Import-CliXml and Export-CliXml might be better.
But for the current situation:
foreach ($sourcexml in Get-ChildItem $SRC_DIR\*.xml) {
    "Translating $($sourcexml) ..." #| Tee-Object -file $LOG_FILE -Append
    $ExportPath = Join-Path -Path $TRN_DIR -ChildPath $sourcexml.Name
    Write-Host $ExportPath
    (Get-Content -Path $sourcexml -Raw) -replace 
    'DATACENTER=.*', "DATACENTER=`"$ValueOne`"" -replace 
    'FOLDER_DSN=.*', "FOLDER_DSN=`"$ValueTwo`"" -replace 
    'FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD=.*', "FOLDER_ORDER_METHOD=`"$ValueThree`"" | 
        Set-Content -LiteralPath $ExportPath
}

